# BotFramework.com Oauth Token Error - 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure, botframework

I have published my code from the Bot Framework Virtual Assistant demo to the Azure Portal. When attempting to chat with the Bot via *Test In Web Chat* I see the following error in Application Insights: *400 Bad Request https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token*

Via Postman, I can confirm that the */botframework.com/* portion of this url doesn't work for me, but I have success when I replace that with our tenant domain. The following article helped me make this discovery: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Due to certain restrictions, it was necessary for me to manually create the Azure App Registration. Based on the following github issue, it is necessary to toggle the *Supported account types* to allow *Accounts in any organizational directory* to access this app: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1068

This point is also emphasized in the following Microsoft Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#manual-app-registration

I need to justify the necessity of this change, so my questions are as follows:

1. What services rely on this *botframework.com* tenant domain? Is it specifically the *Web Chat* tool?
2. Is there a way to change the services dependant on *botframework.com* auth tokens to use our tenant instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The identity of all the connector services (i.e. all the channels) resides in the botframework.com tenant. Web Chat in the portal uses the Direct Line channel and needs to get a token from botframework.com tenant. The token must come from botframework.com tenant for most channels. The only exception to this is Teams and that requires special configuration by the tenant admin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you found this useful, can you please accept it so that it helps others? Thanks

Comment: I did find this useful, Thanks.